# kafka spout configuration error

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, apache-storm

system environment:

storm 0.9.2 incubating

Apache Maven 3.0.5

Java version: 1.7.0_55, vendor: Oracle Corporation

OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-24-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"

here is my code:

```
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.setDebug(true);



        String zkConnString = "localhost:2181";
        String topic = "tap";
        BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zkConnString);


        SpoutConfig kafkaSpoutConfig = new SpoutConfig (hosts, topic, "/" + topic,  UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        kafkaSpoutConfig.bufferSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
        kafkaSpoutConfig.fetchSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;

        kafkaSpoutConfig.ignoreZKOffsets = true;
```

i did storm kafka integration successfully but i need to ignore zookeeper offsets**kafkaSpoutConfig.ignoreZKOffsets = true;** but when i tried to build using maven i got an error.

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ignoreZKOffsets
  location: variable kafkaSpoutConfig of type storm.kafka.SpoutConfig
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

how to ignore zkoffests? please give  an example to use zkoffests..

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the wrong package for SpoutConfig.

Try using **org.apache.storm.kafka.SpoutConfig** (available in **storm-core** maven dependency) instead of **storm.kafka.SpoutConfig** (available in **storm-kafka** maven dependency).